# What is a good asset management software to track offline components?

Tags: monitoring, library

We are currently using Nagios to monitor all of our servers, network devices (routers and switches), printers, and relevant services.

However, how do you monitor items that are not connected to the network?

For instance, we have a library of books and videos that we would like to keep better tabs of.  Plus we have spare monitors, digital cameras, laptops, speakers, keyboards, cables, etc. that we want to make sure are accounted for.

Currently, we are using an Excel spreadsheet, but it's not an elegant solution.

If I can describe an ideal solution it might resemble the following:
Whenever a person borrows a piece of equipment, the software records it.  When they do not return the equipment in the alloted amount of time, we're notified via email.  An added plus might be that it has some sort of scanning component (like barcode scanning) integrated into the software.

I'm happy with Nagios, so I'm looking for something to monitor offline components.  Any recommendations are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Koha](http://koha.org) - probably overkill, but maybe not if you want to track laptops and such as well from multiple offices.  Great thing about it is that it's open source.

EDIT: Yes, it's library software.  Libraries let you check out all kinds of crap these days! :)

EDIT: [Framework link](http://koha.org/documentation/manual/3.2/administration/catalog-administration/marc-bibliographic-frameworks/view?searchterm=custom%20columns)

Comment: Interesting.  It is an enterprise level software for libraries.  In contrast, we're more of an IT shop.  Do you know if it lets you create categories such as laptop, digital camera, equipment, tools, etc.?  And then subcategories under those such as CPU, RAM, type of camera, zoom, equipment type, etc.?

Comment: You can create 'custom frameworks' which would probably meet your needs.  I'll give you that it's a bit of a hack, I would probably re purpose some of the stuff that would be less useful to you.  Since it's open source, it would probably be pretty trivial to change 'Author' to 'Brand' and stuff like that